# T-SQL to SQLite conversion

Tags: sqlite, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL statement for creating a table which I have modified to work with SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE prerequisite_lesson(
   next_lesson_id INT NOT NULL,
   prereq_lesson_id INT NOT NULL,
   CHECK(prereq_lesson_id) NOT (lesson_id),
CONSTRAINT pk_prereq PRIMARY KEY (lesson_id, prereq_lesson_id),
FOREIGN KEY(next_lesson_id) REFERENCES lessons(lesson_id),
FOREIGN KEY(prereq_lesson_id) REFERENCES lessons(lesson_id));
```

I'm getting 4 errors when I try to create the table as follows:

1. Unrecognized data type. (near "(" at position 111)
2. A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "prereq_lesson_id" at position 112)
3. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "prereq_lesson_id" at position 112)
4. Unrecognized statement type. (near "NOT" at position 130)

Can anyone offer help with the errors? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to create `lessons` first.

```
create table lessons(
  lesson_id int primary key not null
);
```

Then there is something with constraint check syntax. Please see an example  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_constraints.htm). Also for primary key pair probably need `next_lesson_id` instead of `lesson_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE prerequisite_lesson(
   next_lesson_id INT NOT NULL,
   prereq_lesson_id INT NOT NULL CHECK(NOT(next_lesson_id)),
   CONSTRAINT pk_prereq PRIMARY KEY (next_lesson_id, prereq_lesson_id),
FOREIGN KEY(next_lesson_id) REFERENCES lessons(lesson_id),
FOREIGN KEY(prereq_lesson_id) REFERENCES lessons(lesson_id));
```

Full schema creation fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f19d5).